# symplectic matrices

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, matrices

If  $( A  B | C  D)$ is a symplectic matrix with entries in the finite field with two elements, is it necessarily the case that 
$\sum_{i,j,k} a_{ij}b_{ij}c_{ik}d_{ik} = 0$?

This arose in connection with some calculations involving theta functions.  There seems to be some indication that it might be true, and I could not come up with a counterexample; but experts in the area may well know the answer right off.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I fixed the math display to look like the one you put into the duplicate post. I hope it is what you want.

Comment: Does $(AB|CD)$ mean $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I assume that `$(AB|CD)=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$` is a block matrix over `$\mathbb F_2$`. Your notation suggests moreover that $A,B,C,D$ are all squares. "symplectic" presumably means that it fixes (infinitesimally) some particular symplectic form, which (if I had to guess) you are taking to be `$(AB|CD)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$`, where by "$1$" I mean the identity square matrix of whatever size you're working with. If this is all correct, fine, but you should edit the question to make precise the notation.

Comment: (and, I guess, since you are over $\mathbb F_2$, $1=-1$ is fine in the matrix.)

Comment: (and maybe, looking at wikipedia, you don't want it to fix the form infinitesimally, but rather honestly).

Comment: Retagged from "symplectic", but I'm not sure I should have.  A "symplectic-matrices" or "symplectic-group" tag would be better than the ambiguous "symplectic" tag, though, so I hope that one dies.